# Send And retrieve data from app.js(node) to javascript(main.js)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I want to send data(username) fom app.js to main.js and also retrieve data(username) from main.js to app.js. I have app.js which is node, calls index.html. The index.html intern calls main.js function clicked. Here is my code.

app.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

var username = 'username';

app.use(express.static('public'))

var request = require('request');
request('http://localhost:8000/test', function (error, response, body){
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
console.log(body);
}
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'))
});

app.listen(3000,'127.0.0.1');
console.log('Listening on port 3000');
```

main.js

```
function clicked() {
var user = document.getElementById('username');
var pass = document.getElementById('password');

var checkuser = "test";
var checkpass = "123"

if (user.value == checkuser) {
    if (pass.value == checkpass) {
        window.location.href = "login.html";
    }
    else
    window.alert("Incorrect username or Password"); 
}
else
    window.alert("Incorrect username or Password");
}
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Login</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet"    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<center>
<h1>LOGIN</h1>
<form action="" method="get">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="well">
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="UserName"></br>
<input type="password" id="password" placeholder="PassWord"></br>
<input type="button" value="Login" onclick="clicked()">
<!--<button type="submit" onclick="clicked()">Login</button>-->
<button type="submit" formaction="register.html">Register</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</center>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use some templating engine like [EJS](http://ejs.co/) to pass data to your HTML page. The template engine generates the final HTML response, that would be sent to the client, by combining the HTML code and the scripts containing logic and the data.

I am not aware of your use case but passing on the username and password to the client and validating them client side is a bad idea. Instead you could make an AJAX call to the server and validate on the server side. Hope it helps.